# Implementing POST/REDIRECT/GET on flask backend

Tags: python, flask, post-redirect-get

I'm a relative beginner in web dev and javascript and I've made a flask app that takes in a user form and puts the data in a table. However, when I reload the template containing the table, the form resubmits. I know that I have to implement a post/redirect/get system and I understand the logic behind it, but in terms of code, I just don't know what I should do.

```
#New Order Page
@app.route('/new-cad-order', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def CAD_order():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        Order_ID = request.form['Order_ID']
        Order_Date = request.form['Order_Date']
        Customer_Name = request.form['Customer_Name']
        Order_Balance_Without_Tax = request.form['Order_Balance_Without_Tax']
        Delivery_Date = request.form['Delivery_Date']
        Final_Order_Balance_With_Tax = request.form['Final_Order_Balance_With_Tax']
        Payment_Date = request.form['Payment_Date']
        Check_Number = request.form['Check_Number']
        Deposit_Date = request.form['Deposit_Date']
        Verification_Date = request.form['Verification_Date']

        key = 'Allow'

        #Processing the data

        return render_template('tracking.html', ID=Order_ID, OrderDate=Order_Date, CustomerName=Customer_Name,
    OrderBalance=Order_Balance_Without_Tax, Downpayment=Downpayment_Balance, Delivery=Order_Delivered, DeliveryDate=Delivery_Date,
    FinalOrderBalance=Final_Order_Balance_With_Tax, RCheck=Revenue_Check, PReceival=Payment_Received, PaymentDate=Payment_Date,
    CheckNum=Check_Number, Deposit=Bank_Deposit, DepositDate=Deposit_Date, Ver=Verification, VerDate=Verification_Date, key=key)

    return render_template('CAD_order.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

After some code fumbling, I found the answer! All I did was change the url of the table template page after registering the new form data. Now the user can't resubmit the form because the method changes to GET.

```
<script>
var table = document.getElementById("orders");
if(localStorage.tableData==undefined){localStorage.tableData=table.innerHTML};
table.innerHTML = localStorage.tableData;

//Registering changes based on form data... 

localStorage.tableData=table.innerHTML;
document.location.href = 'http://localhost:5000/tracking';
  };
```